# word2vec word to color association?

Tags: word2vec, word-embedding

I'm trying to get color associations like so:

```
apple -> red

banana -> yellow

grass -> green

sky -> blue
```

using the GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin vectors, I first tried

```
wv.similarity('apple',color)
```

where color is a primary color, eg 'red','yellow','blue' etc.

with fruits 'orange' is always the highest color association, probably because it conflates the color and the fruit. When I remove orange the results are still strange:

```
apple:

[('violet', 0.24978276994901127), ('green', 0.20656763297902447), ('red', 0.19834849929308024), ('yellow', 0.18963902211016806), ('cyan', 0.17945308073294569), ('blue', 0.13687176308102386)]

cherry:
[('violet', 0.27348741504236473), ('red', 0.25540695681746473), ('yellow', 0.24285150471329794), ('blue', 0.20400566489159569), ('green', 0.18741563150077917), ('cyan', 0.12736182067644364)]

banana:
[('yellow', 0.27708333668133234), ('green', 0.25977272141145935), ('red', 0.24736077659820707), ('violet', 0.23909913025940599), ('cyan', 0.16519069493338848), ('blue', 0.15660144725154587)]
```

so apparently 'violet' aligns with 'apple' and 'cherry' along some other dimension (maybe they're plants?).

I tried formulating it as an analogy. This worked for some objects but doesn't generalize well:

```
wv.most_similar(restrict_vocab=100000, positive=['apple','yellow'], negative=['banana'])
[(u'red', 0.5296207666397095), (u'orange', 0.501822829246521), (u'bright_yellow', 0.49562686681747437), (u'purple', 0.4909234642982483), (u'blue', 0.465557336807251), (u'pink', 0.43768370151519775), (u'colored', 0.4296746551990509), (u'brown', 0.4290006756782532), (u'bright_orange', 0.4261433482170105), (u'yellows', 0.4199957549571991)]

wv.most_similar(restrict_vocab=100000, positive=['grass','yellow'], negative=['banana'])
[(u'bright_yellow', 0.4722655713558197), (u'blue', 0.45448029041290283), (u'red', 0.43442922830581665), (u'lawns', 0.4275570809841156), (u'maroon', 0.4197036325931549), (u'bright_orange', 0.41167205572128296), (u'brown', 0.4110153317451477), (u'purple', 0.4074830412864685), (u'grassy', 0.4017237722873688), (u'striped', 0.40009182691574097)]
```

I also tried the facebook fasttext embeddings but results were worse. How should I approach this problem and isolate the vector for "common color of object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting thing to try, but whether word-vectors would successfully encode these relationships at all seems to me an open question, and any level of success would depend on a lot of particular training choices, including corpus and parameters.

In particular, the `GoogleNews` vector set, trained on published news-stories, might not be as strong in associating fruits-with-colors as other choices. (For example, I'd guess the text of children's books, or transcripts of educational programs, would induce stronger vector-arrangements for this purpose.)

A `violet` is also a flower, so that partially explains its closeness to other fruits. And as you note the prominence of 'orange' as both a fruit and color creates issues when it's involved. There is no disambiguation between multiple word-senses in plain Word2Vec, or the `GoogleNews` vectors, although there's been some research using or creating word-vectors to distinguish alternate word-senses. (Even words like 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'cherry', and 'grass' have alternate meanings that may be affecting vector-positioning.)

I do suspect the analogy/directional approach may have more luck than pure-similarity. (That is, asking "which colorword is in the direction learned from these other objectword->colorword examples?", rather than "which colorword is absolutely closest to this objectword?")

You might want try objectword->colorword example pairs from a larger domain, or try additional vector-math to see if other definitions/composites better match the answers you expect.

For example. maybe your "learn-the-direction" examples should include non-fruits – sky->blue, coal->black, etc.

And I recall seeing once the suggestion that analogy-solving could be improved if many-known-good analogies of the same-relationship were used together, rather than just one. (That is, compose a direction from all of "England:London", "Russia:Moscow", "France:Paris" before probing "Germany:*?*", rather than just one. I'm not sure if adding more vectors to the gensim `most_similar()` `positive`/`negative` lists has the same effect or you need to do the differencing/averaging/norming yourself.)

An interesting paper on interpretation and improvement of analogy results is Levy & Goldberg's "[Linguistic Regularities in Sparse and Explicit Word Representations](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W14-1618)".

There's other work that tries to train or skew word (or concept/entity) vectors to be better at question-answering, which might be relevant, but other than suggesting that as a search term, I don't know any technique that's especially appropriate or ready-to-use in available libraries.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I've tried doing the vector math approach, and it does seem to improve things marginally.


I've just become aware of this project: https://explosion.ai/blog/sense2vec-with-spacy


which should be perfect for this task. I don't think orange and violet have alternate meanings when used as an ADJ, so sense disambiguation along POS lines should yield much better results.